# How to replace a functional (many) OUTER APPLY (SELECT * FROM)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot, unpivot

*Applies to Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2.*

### The problem is

If we have a few dozen `Outer Apply` (30) then they begin to work pretty slowly. In the middle of the `Outer Apply` I have something more complicated than a simple select, a view.

### Details

I'm writing a sort of attributes assigned to tables (in the database). Generally, a few tables, holds a reference to a table of attributes (key, value).

Pseudo structure looks like this:

```
DECLARE @Lot TABLE (
LotId INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
SomeText VARCHAR(8))

INSERT INTO @Lot
OUTPUT INSERTED.*
VALUES ('Hello'), ('World')

DECLARE @Attribute TABLE(
AttributeId INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
LotId INT, 
Val VARCHAR(8),
Kind VARCHAR(8))

INSERT INTO @Attribute
OUTPUT INSERTED.* VALUES 
(1, 'Foo1', 'Kind1'), (1, 'Foo2', 'Kind2'), 
(2, 'Bar1', 'Kind1'), (2, 'Bar2', 'Kind2'), (2, 'Bar3', 'Kind3')

LotId       SomeText
----------- --------
1           Hello
2           World

AttributeId LotId       Val      Kind
----------- ----------- -------- --------
1           1           Foo1     Kind1
2           1           Foo2     Kind2
3           2           Bar1     Kind1
4           2           Bar2     Kind2
5           2           Bar3     Kind3
```

I can now run a query such as:

```
SELECT 
[l].[LotId]
  , [SomeText]
  , [Oa1].[AttributeId]
  , [Oa1].[LotId]
  , 'Kind1Val' = [Oa1].[Val]
  , [Oa1].[Kind]
  , [Oa2].[AttributeId]
  , [Oa2].[LotId]
  , 'Kind2Val' = [Oa2].[Val]
  , [Oa2].[Kind]
  , [Oa3].[AttributeId]
  , [Oa3].[LotId]
  , 'Kind3Val' = [Oa3].[Val]
  , [Oa3].[Kind]  
FROM @Lot AS l
OUTER APPLY(SELECT * FROM @Attribute AS la WHERE la.[LotId] = l.[LotId] AND la.[Kind] = 'Kind1') AS Oa1
OUTER APPLY(SELECT * FROM @Attribute AS la WHERE la.[LotId] = l.[LotId] AND la.[Kind] = 'Kind2') AS Oa2
OUTER APPLY(SELECT * FROM @Attribute AS la WHERE la.[LotId] = l.[LotId] AND la.[Kind] = 'Kind3') AS Oa3


LotId       SomeText AttributeId LotId       Kind1Val Kind     AttributeId LotId       Kind2Val Kind     AttributeId LotId       Kind3Val Kind
----------- -------- ----------- ----------- -------- -------- ----------- ----------- -------- -------- ----------- ----------- -------- --------
1           Hello    1           1           Foo1     Kind1    2           1           Foo2     Kind2    NULL        NULL        NULL     NULL
2           World    3           2           Bar1     Kind1    4           2           Bar2     Kind2    5           2           Bar3     Kind3
```

The **simple** way to get the pivot table of attribute values ​​and results for Lot rows that do not have attribute such a Kind3.
I know Microsoft [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and it is not simple and do not fits here.

Finally, what will be faster and will give the same results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to get the result you can *unpivot* and then *pivot* the data.

There are two ways that you can perform this.  First, you can use the `UNPIVOT` and the `PIVOT` function:

```
select *
from
(
    select LotId,
        SomeText,
        col+'_'+CAST(rn as varchar(10)) col,
        value
    from
    (
        select l.LotId, 
            l.SomeText,
            cast(a.AttributeId as varchar(8)) attributeid,
            cast(a.LotId as varchar(8)) a_LotId,
            a.Val,
            a.Kind,
            ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by l.lotid order by a.attributeid) rn
        from @Lot l
        left join @Attribute a
            on l.LotId = a.LotId
    ) src
    unpivot
    (
        value
        for col in (attributeid, a_Lotid, val, kind)
    ) unpiv
) d
pivot
(
    max(value)
    for col in (attributeid_1, a_LotId_1, Val_1, Kind_1,
                attributeid_2, a_LotId_2, Val_2, Kind_2,
                attributeid_3, a_LotId_3, Val_3, Kind_3)
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/10812).

Or starting in SQL Server 2008+, you can use `CROSS APPLY` with a `VALUES` clause to unpivot the data:

```
select *
from
(
    select LotId,
        SomeText,
        col+'_'+CAST(rn as varchar(10)) col,
        value
    from
    (
        select l.LotId, 
            l.SomeText,
            cast(a.AttributeId as varchar(8)) attributeid,
            cast(a.LotId as varchar(8)) a_LotId,
            a.Val,
            a.Kind,
            ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by l.lotid order by a.attributeid) rn
        from @Lot l
        left join @Attribute a
            on l.LotId = a.LotId
    ) src
    cross apply
    (
        values ('attributeid', attributeid),('LotId', a_LotId), ('Value', Val), ('Kind', Kind)
    ) c (col, value)
) d
pivot
(
    max(value)
    for col in (attributeid_1, LotId_1, Value_1, Kind_1,
                attributeid_2, LotId_2, Value_2, Kind_2,
                attributeid_3, LotId_3, Value_3, Kind_3)
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/10813).

The unpivot process takes the multiple columns for each `LotID` and `SomeText` and converts it into rows giving the result:

```
| LOTID | SOMETEXT |           COL | VALUE |
--------------------------------------------
|     1 |    Hello | attributeid_1 |     1 |
|     1 |    Hello |       LotId_1 |     1 |
|     1 |    Hello |       Value_1 |  Foo1 |
|     1 |    Hello |        Kind_1 | Kind1 |
|     1 |    Hello | attributeid_2 |     2 |
```

I added a `row_number()` to the inner subquery to be used to create the new column names to pivot.  Once the names are created the pivot can be applied to the new columns giving the final result

This could also be done using dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(col+'_'+rn) 
                    from 
                    (
                      select 
                        cast(ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by l.lotid order by a.attributeid) as varchar(10)) rn
                      from Lot l
                      left join Attribute a
                          on l.LotId = a.LotId
                    ) t
                    cross apply (values ('attributeid', 1),
                                 ('LotId', 2), 
                                 ('Value', 3), 
                                 ('Kind', 4)) c (col, so)
                    group by col, rn, so
                    order by rn, so
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query = 'SELECT LotId,
                    SomeText,' + @cols + ' 
             from 
             (
                select LotId,
                    SomeText,
                    col+''_''+CAST(rn as varchar(10)) col,
                    value
                from
                (
                    select l.LotId, 
                        l.SomeText,
                        cast(a.AttributeId as varchar(8)) attributeid,
                        cast(a.LotId as varchar(8)) a_LotId,
                        a.Val,
                        a.Kind,
                        ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by l.lotid order by a.attributeid) rn
                    from Lot l
                    left join Attribute a
                        on l.LotId = a.LotId
                ) src
                cross apply
                (
                    values (''attributeid'', attributeid),(''LotId'', a_LotId), (''Value'', Val), (''Kind'', Kind)
                ) c (col, value)
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for col in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b31af/12)

All three versions will give the same result:

```
| LOTID | SOMETEXT | ATTRIBUTEID_1 | LOTID_1 | VALUE_1 | KIND_1 | ATTRIBUTEID_2 | LOTID_2 | VALUE_2 | KIND_2 | ATTRIBUTEID_3 | LOTID_3 | VALUE_3 | KIND_3 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     1 |    Hello |             1 |       1 |    Foo1 |  Kind1 |             2 |       1 |    Foo2 |  Kind2 |        (null) |  (null) |  (null) | (null) |
|     2 |    World |             3 |       2 |    Bar1 |  Kind1 |             4 |       2 |    Bar2 |  Kind2 |             5 |       2 |    Bar3 |  Kind3 |
```

Comment: You are a pivot geek! `('!-)`

Comment: @Kaf I prefer nerd, but yes I am aware.

Comment: +1 for rejecting the term **geek**, particularly in light of some of the more colorful, historical usages ( see http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/77307?rskey=fHnqwr&result=1#eid )

Comment: SET STATISTICS IO ON gives: Scan count 3, logical reads 15 VS Scan count 1, logical reads 5 in Your solution. I'll try on real data now.

Comment: But, what if I:  
    DELETE FROM Attribute;
    INSERT INTO Attribute VALUES (2, 'Bar2', 'Kind2'), (2, 'Bar1', 'Kind8'), (2, 'Bar3', 'Kind3'), (1, 'Foo1', 'Kind1');  Sometimes I have Lot with full attributes set and sometimes with only few.

Comment: @Tomasito I am not sure what you are asking.

Comment: @Kaf I strongly agree `:D` I call her the *The Goddess of Pivots*

Comment: @bluefeet Look at http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/10842 Kind_1="Kind2", Kind_2 is "Kind8". It depends on data insert order.

Comment: @Tomasito Then what do you want the order to be?

Comment: @bluefeet look at http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/55da1/6 that's what I'm trying to achieve. Can I accomplish this without `AttributeMask` table?

Comment: @Tomasito My suggestion is to post another question with the details of your new issue, it will prevent the back and forth in the comments and then you can provide a full picture of your needs. :)

Comment: @bluefeet Good suggestion. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397144/sorting-data-for-pivot-source Thank you very much for the help so far, was 100% accurate.