# Measure SQL performance without using profiler

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance-testing, database-performance

Are there simpler ways to measure SQL performance in MS-SQL than using profiler?

I have been using this script I found on the internet and it gives me measurements, but I don't know how accurate it may be.

```
DECLARE @StartTime datetime;

DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS  -- Force data/index pages out of buffer cache for valid test
SET @StartTime = GETDATE() -- Measurement Starts  

-->Insert SQL CALL/Script here

-- Measurement Ends  
SELECT ExecutionTimeInMS = DATEDIFF(millisecond, @StartTime, getdate())
GO
```

Are there similar alternatives to get a quick and dirty, generally accurate pulse on the choices I'm making?

It has returned some surprising results, but I don't where to direct the surprise, at the test queries or the the test tool/script?

Comment: Where is this `interwebs`?

Comment: Profiler, Execution plans, statistics time and io. Those are the tools to use. Dropping buffer over and over will give you poor metrics.

Comment: Yes, this works fine for benchmarking base response time and resource consumption of a single query or procedure.  This works best when tuning a single query, to iteratively compare it to previous versions of itself.  It's not so good for looking at whole server/application performance (nigh-useless).

Answer (score 2):

Here is my test setup:

```
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
DBCC freeproccache

SET STATISTICS IO ON
SET STATISTICS TIME ON

SELECT * FROM sys.all_columns
```

that gives you nice output (on messages tab):

```
(4307 row(s) affected)
Table 'syscolrdb'. Scan count 1, logical reads 167, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 167, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'syscolpars'. Scan count 1, logical reads 12, physical reads 1, read-ahead reads 10, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 78 ms,  elapsed time = 738 ms.
```

Comment: This is the nice way to do this just from a client window.  As others point out, it's always important to understand your environment - make sure you're testing on a system as similar to the end one as possible.  But all that understood, SET STATISTICS TIME ON is a great way to dump times. It gives one for each major operation and an overall time batch time (a little confusing the first time you try it) ...  if possible, one related trick is to put "print" statements in your batch at each step, and then these will show up right next to the times.

Comment: Also `SET STATISTICS IO ON` is quick, dirty way to figure out something is wrong with you query. Example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15365367/how-to-replace-a-functional-many-outer-apply-select-from if amount of data is known we'll see, that in first solution is too many reads from table.

Answer (score 0):

Before dropping buffers you should set a `checkpoint` to force all dirty pages to disk. 
Anyway, dropping buffers may be a choice while playing at the test system. Performance of SQL queries largely depends on the data in the DB as well as the type, frequency, parameters and result sets of queries run on that DB.

Running queries on a "clean" single-user system produces results for the clean single-user system. Buffer management is a core function of a DBMS so i don't see a point in arbitrary flushing the buffers and measure an execution time value. In addition, doing that on a production system may likely decrease overall performance and therefore affect the query to be tested too.

To optimize a single query, use the execution plan and identify parts of the query which account for the highest share and see if you can do anything about it. For example, if you have ill designed indexes which do not fit your data, execution time will mean nothing but the execution plan will give you a hint.

To identify queries worth optimization effort use the profiler the find a) resource consuming queries (e.g. long running) and b) frequently used queries.

To monitor an overall system use the performance counters and have an eye on the memory and I/O subsystem, e.g. the paging counters.

Comment: I was looking for a quick and dirty test to demonstrate speed of queries. If I were teaching a class of 19 students, wouldn't 19 people running profiler bring the whole system to its knees? How do you quickly DEMONSTRATE the where id = (select id from other_table) is a bad idea?

Comment: I see and i do understand, i had similar issues before. What i tried to explain is that there is no simple metric you can use. You can measure the execution time but what do you do with that value? You cannot go to another developer and tell him "hey 5 ms is too slow it should be 2 ms". Buffer flushing may be useful to compare different versions of a query but even that will not guarantee same results on a live box.

Comment: For demonstration purposes that is quite ok i think. But as i said i would only demonstrate on a test environment.

Comment: If I use checkpoint, any data that was in the buffers would be saved then, correct? or is this something I have to revert back to when I'm done?

Comment: Nothing to worry about. The DBMS will write pages which have been changed by non-committed transaction to the disk (=DB) to free buffer space. Writing dirty pages to the DB requires the DBMS to store UNDO information but that is something completely internal. You don't have to revert something by yourself.